# Resize CSV data using Python and Keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, keras, deep-learning

I have CSV files that I need to feed to a Deep-Learning network. Currently my CSV files are of size 360*480, but the network restricts them to be of size 224*224. I am using Python and Keras for the deep-learning part. So how can I resize the matrices?

I was thinking that since aspect ratio is 3:4, so if I resize them to 224:(224*4/3) = 224:299, and then crop the width of the matrix to 224, it could serve the purpose. But I cannot find a suitable function to do that. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a short and simple way to solve this. This uses the *Python Image Library*/*[Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html/)*.

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from PIL import Image

matrix = np.array(list(csv.reader(open('./path/mat.csv', "r"), delimiter=","))).astype("uint8")  #read csv
imgObj = Image.fromarray(matrix)  #convert matrix to Image object
resized_imgObj = img.resize((224,224))  #resize Image object
imgObj.show()
resized_imgObj.show()
resized_matrix = np.asarray(img)  #convert Image object to matrix
```

While numpy module also has a [resize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html/) function, but it is not as useful as the aforementioned way.

When I tried it, the resized matrix had lost all the intricacies and aesthetic aspect of the original matrix. This is probably due to the fact that *numpy.ndarray.resize* **doesn't interpolate** and **missing entries are filled with zeros**.

So, for this case *Image.resize()* is more useful.

Comment: Been looking for this for a while, but I've got a question, can I use pandas to read my csv file instead of csv.reader line 
and then run the following code in a for statement to work on each image at once

Comment: @Dhouibiiheb Yeah surely, pandas can be used to read the .csv file. You just have to make sure it's a np array before the next step.

Comment: and after ensuring it's an array matrix, all images are in the same array matrix right ?
so imgObj  variable will contain all images or just the first one ? can you please explain it

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for [cv.resize()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) if you're using images.
If not, try [numpy.ndarray.resize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.resize.html)

Comment: Thanks. But after reading and before truncating, how can I resize the matrix keeping aspect ratio same.
Is there any kind of short way / inbuilt method in keras that helps me resize data into the conventional 224*224 ?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you're asking then. Your input is a image? Then this edit should help

Answer (score 2):

### Image processing

If you want to do nontrivial alterations to the data *as images* (i.e. interpolating between pixel values, assuming that they represent photographs) then you might want to use proper image processing libraries for that.  You'd need to treat them not as raw matrixes (csv of numbers) but convert them to rgb images, do the transformations you desire, and convert them back to a numpy matrix.

OpenCV (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d6e/tutorial_py_geometric_transformations.html)
or Pillow (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html) might be useful to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could also convert the csv file to a list, truncate the list, and then convert the list to a numpy array and then use np.reshape.

Comment: Thanks. But isn't reshape related to converting something like 3*6 to 2*9, like that. I mean in reshape total number of elements remain same. But here I want to get a matrix that has same aspect ratio but lesser elements. Something more like a 'crop' ...

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure how to help. I'll delete this post soon.